# $_GET does not equal variable

Tags: php, get, profile

So, I'm making a profile page, and I need to have it so it displays other content if it's not your username in the URL. How would i go about doing this, considering this doesn't seem to be working.

```
else if(isset($_GET[!$myUsername])){
        echo "hi";
    }
```

Thank You!

Comment: look where the **!** was added

Answer (score 2):

Its probably a bad idea to pass a username in the url ($_GET holds the url parameters)

I would start by reading up on php sessions here is a quick tutorial:
http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpsessions.php

The exact answer to your question is is the placement of the the "!", it needs to be moved in front of isset().

```
if (!isset($_GET['myUserName'])) {
    //this is true when ?mysuername= is not present in the address bar. 
}
```

After you read up on the sessions you will handle this by setting a a session variable, something names "loggedIn" or similar.

```
if (isset($_SESSION['loggedIn'])) {
   //Show Logged IN Content
   echo "Your user id is: ". $_SESSION['userId'];
} else {
   //Show not logged in content
   echo "You should probably log in before trying to look at this content";
}
```